# number of nodes in a decision tree

Tags: decision-trees

I don't know how to prove/disprove this:

In a decision tree for sort algorithm there are at least $2^{n!}$ nodes. I know that the number of leaves is $n!$

Comment: so the statemant is incorrect?

Comment: A decision tree of $n!$ leaves cannot have $2^{n!}$ nodes !

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: "The quickest route to sorting is dichotomy": what does that mean ? And how can a full binary tree of $n$ leaves have $2^n$ nodes ???

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: a full tree of $n$ leaves has $2n-1$ nodes, not $2^n-1$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sorting algorithm is able to identify any permutation of a sorted array of $n$ elements, and there are $n!$ such permutations.

Hence, assuming that we can always choose decisions that halve the subset of possible permutations, the height of the decision tree won't exceed $\lceil\log_2n!\rceil$, corresponding to a complete tree of $2^{\lceil\log_2n!\rceil}-1$ nodes.

---

As it turns out that we do have worst-case $O(n\log n)$ sorting algorithm (such as HeapSort), $\Theta(\lceil\log_2n!\rceil)$ is a tight bound for the height.

This corresponds to $2^{\Theta(\lceil\log_2n!\rceil)}=O(n!^c)$ nodes for some $c$. Using results for Heapsort, the upper bound of the decision tree must be no worse than $O(n!^2)$.